# Keyboard shortcuts in gnome-classic

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

I am using gnome-classic in ubuntu 11.10 & I am not able to figure out the shortcut for the "Applications" list and "Places" list.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for Applications drop down and "Run Application" dialog.

Comment: Is there some way to change Alt+F1 to the Super bottom?